# How Do I Convert a yuv420 Video File to 16-bit (using ffmpeg)?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, yuv

As the title says, my video file has 12-bit depth and I want to convert it to 16-bit. I dont care which yuv pixel format, as long as its 16 bit. I have installed ffmpeg and I can't figure out what combination of arguments to use to convert it. The video file is very small: 20 frames at 352x288.

This is the command I have been trying, but the file size is the same number of bytes as the original:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 352x288 -pixel_format yuv420p -sample_fmt s16 -i inpput.yuv output.yuv
```

If there is another way to do this without ffmpeg, I am open to any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`
2. Pick your favorite format with `BIT_DEPTHS="16-16-16"` or `16`
3. Use `-pix_fmt xxx` output option in your command.

Make sure your codec supports it. To check, run `ffmpeg -h encoder=xxx` where `xxx` is the codec name and look for a line starting with `Supported pixel formats:`. For example, `libx264` spits out

```
Supported pixel formats: yuv420p yuvj420p yuv422p yuvj422p yuv444p yuvj444p nv12 nv16 nv21 yuv420p10le yuv422p10le yuv444p10le nv20le gray gray10le
```

Also, your input options don't make sense...

1. `-pixel_format yuv420p` means the yuv file is only 8-bits
2. `-sample_fmt`  is an audio option. yuv file is video only.